# Bonjour -How to get the IP address to uniquely identify each client connected to the network

Tags: ios, swift, bonjour, nsnetservice, nsnetservicebrowser

I'm not well versed in networking but I'm firing up my own Bonjour service to find nearby users. I read this [blog post](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ZQMYnq6KQvoJ:https://www.whatsoniphone.com/blog/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/%20&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) and it says:

> Socket represents a unique communication endpoint on the network. When
>   your app needs to exchange data with another app, it creates a socket
>   and uses it to connect to the other app’s socket. You can both send
>   and receive data through the same socket. Each socket has an IP
>   address and a port number (between 1 and 65535) associated with it. **IP
>   address uniquely identifies each computer on a given network** and port
>   number uniquely identifies a network socket on that computer.

`NetServiceBrowser` has a delegate method that discovers nearby users:

```
func netServiceBrowser(_ browser: NetServiceBrowser, didFind service: NetService, moreComing: Bool) {

    print(service.domain)
    print(service.name)
    print(service.type)
    print(service.addresses as Any)
    print(service.hostName as Any)
    print(service.port)
}
```

It also has a method that I need to use to allow them to actually connect with each other:

```
func netService(_ sender: NetService,
                didAcceptConnectionWith inputStream: InputStream,
                outputStream stream: OutputStream) {
    print("netServiceDidAcceptConnection:\(sender)");
}
```

Once users are connected with each other and start sharing data I need to create an array with something that uniquely identifies each of them. I would like to use the `device's IP Address` but I don't see one returned from the `didFind` delegate method. **What can I use in place to uniquely identify each device?**

Comment: You can obtain IP Address from `service.addresses` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12558305/how-to-get-ip-address-from-netservice/18428117

Comment: @iUrii thanks for link! I’ll look into it. Cheers  